# Force IDA to redo SP analysis?

Tags: ida, disassembly

I had a function which I was unable to decompile due to a positive SP value, I tried to change it manually but accidentaly made everything worse, is there a way to restore/make IDA redo the original analysis so I can get the orignal values? I already tried undefining the code region and defining it again but it didn't work